# How can I select all elements except those inside divs with particular classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to find a way to select all the makes of cars except those that are inside a div with the class `discontinued` or `scrapped`. Here's my markup:

```css
div:not(.discontinued):not(.scrapped) > .make {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">NISSAN</div>
    <div class="model">MICRA</div>
</div>
<div class="discontinued">
    <div class="car">
        <div class="make">FORD</div>
        <div class="model">MONDEO</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scrapped">
    <div class="car">
        <div class="make">SEAT</div>
        <div class="model">IBIZA</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scrapped">
    <div class="preowned">
        <div class="car">
            <div class="make">BMW</div>
            <div class="model">100</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">HONDA</div>
    <div class="model">INTEGRA</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">PEUGEOT</div>
    <div class="model">206</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">TOYOTA</div>
    <div class="model">COROLLA</div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, I tried the following:

```
div:not(.discontinued):not(.scrapped) > .make
```

...but this still included `FORD`, `SEAT`, and `BMW`.

Comment: You can add another class name to div with car classes that aren’t inside these specific divs and then you can select all car classes which have the new class name your css would be like: .car.newClass

Comment: @monala92 I am not able to modify the HTML unfortunately. I'm hoping there's a way to work with what I have.

Comment: I have edited my example to illustrate that the `car` node is not always a direct child of `discontinued` and `scrapped` but may still be inside them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately CSS selectors cannot traverse up parent elements, so if you are just trying to style them differently you may want to reverse your thought process and select ones that *are* `.discontinued` or `.scrapped` and apply overriding styles:

```css
.model {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.make {
  color: green;
}

.scrapped .make,
.discontinued .make {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">NISSAN</div>
    <div class="model">MICRA</div>
</div>
<div class="discontinued">
    <div class="car">
        <div class="make">FORD</div>
        <div class="model">MONDEO</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scrapped">
    <div class="car">
        <div class="make">SEAT</div>
        <div class="model">IBIZA</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scrapped">
    <div class="preowned">
        <div class="car">
            <div class="make">SEAT</div>
            <div class="model">IBIZA</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">HONDA</div>
    <div class="model">INTEGRA</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">PEUGEOT</div>
    <div class="model">206</div>
</div>
<div class="car">
    <div class="make">TOYOTA</div>
    <div class="model">COROLLA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to behave the same way. FORD and SEAT are still included.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after another user posted an answer that the `div` tag is also selecting the `.car` elements which I overlooked - I added an alternative to putting the modifying classes on the `.car` element to address that.

Comment: I can't change my HTML. Also I can't rely on the .car class being the second level nested class- there may be another div wrapped around it.

Comment: Would have been nice to know beforehand xD - are there any other qualifiers for the structure? Could you provide examples of each?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I'll amend the example to reflect this. Can't think of any other qualifiers.

Comment: @Urbycoz I've edited my question in hopes this is getting you closer to you answer!

Comment: Yeah I think having two separate clauses might be the best way to solve this, rather than trying to do it in one. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this style code,

```css
div.make:not(.discontinued .make):not(.scrapped .make) {
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: Answer is unclear if it's working. It would be better with html to show live working example.